# How to compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-1}{t^{s+1}}dt$

Tags: integration

I came across the following integral in a textbook without explanation. How can I prove it?

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-1}{t^{s+1}}dt=\Gamma(-s)$$

Here $s\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Maybe use $$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x} dx$$?

Comment: See [The gamma function](https://brilliant.org/wiki/gamma-function/?subtopic=integration&chapter=advanced-integration)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $0<s<1$. Then $1-s>0$ and
$$\Gamma(1-s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t^s}\,dt.$$
Integrate by parts:
$$\Gamma(1-s)=\left[\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t^s}\right]_0^\infty
+\int_0^\infty\frac{s(1-e^{-t})}{t^{s+1}}\,dt
=s\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t^{s+1}}\,dt.$$
But $\Gamma(1-s)=-s\Gamma(-s)$.

Comment: I have a confusion here (probably a silly question). How does $\left[\dfrac{1 - e^{-t}}{t^s}\right]$ evaluate to $0$? At $t = 0$, doesn't it become undefined (division by $0$)?

Comment: @an4s Take it as a limit.

Comment: The numerator is $O(t)$ as $t\to0$ @an4s

Comment: @mickep Ah, that makes sense. For anybody else with the same question, I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Definition) helpful as well.

Answer (score -3):

Since $s\in(0,1)$ and :
$$  \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^{s+1}}dt=0 $$
we have:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-1}{t^{s+1}}dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{s+1}}dt-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^{s+1}}dt= \int_0^\infty t^{-s-1}e^{-t} dt-0=  \int_0^\infty t^{(-s)-1}e^{-t} dt =\Gamma (-s)$$

Comment: Your first line is completely wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLi What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's divergent for the given $s$s because your lower bound is 0.

Comment: Yes but there is 0<s<1

Comment: Have you tried $s=0.5$?